# Calculator with Joomla Fabrik

Tags: javascript, joomla3.0

I use fabrik and I want to make a calculator with two inputs and a button. I am new to Joomla and to fabrik.

I noticed that I can add a javascript to a button, but I don´t know how to relate the tow inputs with the button...

Some help will be apreciated

Comment: do you have an Idea about how javascript work in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a form and setup your elements and add whatever javascript you want to your elements

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).